# functional programming in kotlin - assigning function

Tags: syntax, functional-programming, kotlin

There is an `arrayOf` function in kotlin. I want to have the same under different name. I tried:

```
val each = ::arrayOf<UUID>
val each = ::arrayOf
val each = ::<UUID>arrayOf
val each = arrayOf
```

I get only compilation errors. is it possible in kotlin? how? or do i have to repeat the whole signature and invocation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work because `arrayOf` is an [inline function with a reified type parameter](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters). It's not possible to store this reified type parameter as part of a function reference or to pass it when invoking the function through a function reference.

If you want to have an alias for this function, you need to define it differently:

```
inline fun <reified T> each(vararg x: T) = arrayOf(*x)
```